# Bold text in text of the axis in R using TeX()

Tags: r, fonts, latex

How to render bold text in plot in R using `TeX`?

```
TeX("$\\alpha$")
TeX("The ratio of 1 and 2 is $\\frac{1}{2}$")

a <- 1:100
plot(a, a^2, xlab=TeX("$\\alpha$ bold text"), ylab=TeX("$\\alpha^2$ bold text"))
```

I tried `TeX("$\\alpha$ \textbf{bold text}")` and `TeX("$\\alpha$ $\textbf{bold text}$")` without success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make beta italic and bold in axis label and P italic and bold in text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458090/how-to-make-beta-italic-and-bold-in-axis-label-and-p-italic-and-bold-in-text)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots

Comment: Thank you for your comment Masoud

Comment: For those who downvoted my question, I would be glad to have the reason why the question was downvoted: If 1. the style of the question or the accuracy of the question is not good enough, just write it : I'm very eager to learn and improve how to write better questions. If it’s 2. because the question is a duplicate, just write as an answer: I would more than glad to upvote it and accept it as an answer. If 3. there is another reason that I didn’t get please write it as well. But I must say that I find the attitude of just downvoting “for free” without any explanation irritating and useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(latex2exp)

TeX("$\\alpha$")
TeX("The ratio of 1 and 2 is $\\frac{1}{2}$")

a <- 1:100
plot(a, a^2, xlab=TeX("$\\alpha$ \\textbf{bold text}"), ylab=TeX("$\\alpha^2$ \\textbf{bold text}"))
```

You need to use double slash in front of the command, then you will get the result:

[image]